# Why is the array not printing out here? (c++)

Tags: c++

The array I have is

```
int age[5] = {11,2,23,4,15}
```

but it does not print out `11,2,23,4, 15`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int age[5] = {11,2,23,4,15};
  
  cout << age[5] << endl;
}
```

Comment: `age[5]` prints out the 6th element of the array (since arrays start at index 0), and that element doesn't exist.  You need to loop over the array and print out each element manually.

Comment: I find it amazing how common this misunderstanding about arrays is. The idea that `age[5]` represents the 'whole array' is not stated by any text book or You Tube video, no matter how poor in quality. It's arising entirely in the heads of the many newbies who think it's true, who I guess must be oblivious to the difference between a declaration and an expression.

Comment: @john To be fair, it's not hard to see where the misunderstanding comes from. Basic declarations look like `type name = initializer`; it's not really the newcomers' fault that they are as-yet unaware that the reality is far more complex than that. It's the language's fault. Though they should read their books in more detail too, rather than guessing then just giving up when it doesn't work.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings But (using the example above) presumably it's known that `age[0]` is the first element of the array, and `age[1]` is the second etc. Yet the meaning of `age[n]` suddenly changes when n is the same as the size of the array? It would be a strange language where that was true.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the array is not `age[5]`.

The name of the array is `age`.

The expression `age[5]` represents the array's sixth element, which does not exist.

In fact, there is no built-in logic for printing a whole array in a formatted manner, so even `cout << age << endl` is not correct.

If you want to print the array, do it element-by-element in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are 0-indexed.  In your example, the valid indexes are 0..4.  You are trying to print a single `int` from `age[5]`, which is out of bounds.

You need to loop through the indexes of the array, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int age[5] = {11,2,23,4,15};
  
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      cout << age[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  array<int, 5> age{11,2,23,4,15};
  
  for(int val : age) {
      cout << val << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```